# Node.js and asynchronous programming with Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

Is the following the correct way to go about things? This is a sign up controller action. Im creating a user and a group to add the user to. Notice I have method level variables called user and group. The rest of the code is asynchronous using the Q module.

Is it ok to have the method level variables or will they be overriden by the another person signing up at the same time?

```
exports.postSignUp = function(req, res, next) {

    var user,
        group;

    return Q.invoke(exports, 'parseUser', req, null)
        .then(function(u)
        {
            user = u;
            return Q.invoke(exports, 'postCreateUser', user).fail(function(err) { throw err; });
        })
        .then(function()
        {
            group = new Group();
            group.userIds = [user._id];
            return Q.invoke(exports, 'postCreateGroup', group).fail(function(err) { throw err; });
        })
        .then(function()
        {
            user.groupId = group._id;
            group.userIds = [ user._id ];
        })
        .then(function()
        {
            return Q.ninvoke(req, 'login', user).fail(function(err) { throw err; });
        })
        .then(function()
        {
            return res.redirect('/tour');
        })
        .fail(function (err)
        {
            console.log('u:' + user);
            console.log('g:' + group);
            return exports.createValidationError(error, req, res, user);
        });
};
```

Comment: Didn't that work for you? What exactly is your question?

Comment: It worked perfectly. My questions are:
1. is it ok to have var user, group on top outside of the "Q". Will the next request to the controller impact those variables?
2. Do I really need to break down all the different steps into different functions or can I just have 1 async function?

Comment: Notice that `.fail(function(err) { throw err; })` can be omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it ok to have the method level variables or will they be overriden by the another person signing up at the same time?

No, they won't as they are locally scoped to your `postSignUp` function.

It is however a little ugly, nesting them might be the better choice here:

```
exports.postSignUp = function(req, res, next) {
    return Q.invoke(exports, 'parseUser', req, null).then(function(user) {
        return Q.invoke(exports, 'postCreateUser', user).then(function(createdUser) {
            var group = new Group();
            group.userIds = [user._id];
            return Q.invoke(exports, 'postCreateGroup', group).then(function(createdGroup) {
                user.groupId = group._id;
                group.userIds = [ user._id ]; // repeat this?

                return Q.ninvoke(req, 'login', user)
            }).then(function(loggedInuser) {
                return res.redirect('/tour');
            }).fail(function(err) {
               console.log('g:' + group);
               throw err;
            });
        }).fail(function(err) {
            console.log('u:' + user);
            return exports.createValidationError(error, req, res, user);
        });
    }) // .fail(function(err) {
       //     … // parseUser or createValidationError failed
       // });
};
```

> Do I really need to break down all the different steps into different functions or can I just have 1 async function?

You have one async function currently, you might want to break that down into creating a user with a new group, and logging him in plus redirecting him to `/tour`.